# How to find timestamp after 10 minutes in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find the time after 10 minutes using `date` command in shell.

Comment: `sleep 600 ; date`? You can [edit] your post with more specifics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @ekaj of course not, it's a hot network question!

Answer (score 15):

try:

```
date -d "+ 10 minutes"
```

The `date` command is quite flexible about the text that you can use. For instance:

```
date -d "next Tuesday"
```

And you can choose the output format as well, for instance if you want as seconds since epoch:

```
date -d "3 weeks" +%s
```

Comment: For those of us who like to spell things out, `"now + 10 minutes"` or `"now + 3 weeks"` also works.

Comment: Can also use `10min`.